# I have text to speech that says the button text but all buttons speak the first button's text

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I just completed the coding to have the text to speech button read the text on the button the user pressed.For some reason every button says the text on the first button instead of their own text. Obviously this is a problem because you don't want every button saying the same thing. It registers no errors in my LogCat so it works fine, just not the way I want it to. I don't have the java experience to find the source of the problem.

```
public class menu extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener,
        OnClickListener {

    TextToSpeech mTts;
    Button speakButton, infoButton, voiceButton;

    // TTS object
    public TextToSpeech myTTS;
    // status check code
    public int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle aboutmenu) {
        super.onCreate(aboutmenu);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainx);

        SpeakingAndroid speak = new SpeakingAndroid();

        VoiceRecognition voiceinput = new VoiceRecognition();

        // get a reference to the button element listed in the XML layout
        speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
        infoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutbutton);
        voiceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.voicebutton);

        // listen for clicks
        infoButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);


        // check for TTS data
        Intent checkTTSIntent = new Intent();
        checkTTSIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkTTSIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);



        voiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

    }
    public void onClick1(View about) {

        // get the text entered
        infoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.aboutbutton);
        String words = infoButton.getText().toString();
        speakWords(words);
        Intent infoIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.INFOSCREEN");
        startActivity(infoIntent);

    }
    // respond to button clicks
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // get the text entered
        speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
        String words = speakButton.getText().toString();
        speakWords(words);
        Intent voiceIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.RECOGNITIONMENU");
        startActivity(voiceIntent);

    }



    // speak the user text
    public void speakWords(String speech) {

        // speak straight away
        myTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    // act on result of TTS data check
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                // the user has the necessary data - create the TTS
                myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            } else {
                // no data - install it now
                Intent installTTSIntent = new Intent();
                installTTSIntent
                        .setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installTTSIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    // setup TTS
    public void onInit(int initStatus) {

        // check for successful instantiation
        if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            if (myTTS.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.US) == TextToSpeech.LANG_AVAILABLE)
                myTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        } else if (initStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry! Text To Speech failed...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: it seems that whatever is in the parenthesis of the first speakWords(words); is what it says for all of the buttons instead of just the first button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a text to speech attribute in your activity

```
private TextToSpeech    mTTS;
```

Instantiate your Text to speech Object in your Activity

```
mTTS=new TextToSpeech(this,this);
```

Get a reference to your buttons listed in the XML layout

```
speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);
infoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_about);
voiceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_voice);
```

Listen to ClickEvents for your Button, your activity must implement the `View.OnClickListener` interface

```
infoButton.setOnClickListener(this);
speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
voiceButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Handle Click Events in th Overriden onClick() method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.btn_speak:
            mTTS.speak(speakButton.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
        case R.id.btn_about:
            mTTS.speak(infoButton.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
        case R.id.btn_voice:
            mTTS.speak(voiceButton.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot all about using switch, case.